# What is the difference between the file descriptor, open file description, and inode?

Tags: linux, memory, storage

1. What is the correspondence/difference between file descriptors and open file descriptions?
2. What is the correspondence/difference between file descriptions and inodes?

Comment: Typo: descripttors, what is an open file description?

Comment: I am guessing the OP is referring to file _descriptors_ and have edited accordingly.

Comment: @terdon [Open File Description](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_258)

Comment: Oh. Well, TIL! Thanks, @KamilMaciorowski.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head... a file descriptor is a numeric reference held by a process which references an ["open file description"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_258) in the kernel.  The open file description holds information about which file is open, what mode (read/write) and *where* in the file the next read or write will be applied to.

[Inodes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode#:%7E:text=POSIX%20inode%20description,-The%20POSIX%20standard&text=An%20inode%20is%20denoted%20by,file%20within%20the%20whole%20system.) are not directly linked to any process. They are a feature of the file system.  They hold meta data such as file ownership.  If a file has multiple file names (it has been hard linked) then it will still only have one inode.

Answer (score -1):

File descriptor is an element in the array which OS gives your application. You always have such array - OS creates it when starts a new process. OS often fills first three elements with pointers to stdin, stdout, and stderr.

Open file descriptor is an array element which points to some file. You call `open()`, OS looks for a an empty element in the array and use it. Conversely, closed/not opened file descriptor is an array element which is empty (or logically empty).

inode - unique (inside the drive) identifier for a file on that drive.